# Как связать условие Javascript c PHP

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

Есть база в ней находятся url.
Мне надо проверить урл на ошибку, если она есть то удалить из БД. 
В JavaScript не селен, как связать JavaScript и PHP?
Или как можно написать цикл и запросы на удаление из БД в JS

```
 <?
include ("conect.php");
$pos = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `table 1`");
while ($pos_result=$pos->fetch_assoc()):
{
$url = $pos_result['url'];
$name = $pos_result['name'];
?>
 <script type="text/javascript">
var XHR = ("onload" in new XMLHttpRequest()) ? XMLHttpRequest : XDomainRequest;
var xhr = new XHR();
xhr.open('GET', <?$url?>, true);
xhr.onload = function() {
}
xhr.onerror = function() {
<?
$db->query("DELETE FROM `table 1` WHERE `name` == $name ");
?>
}
xhr.send();
</script> 
<?
}
endwhile;
?>
```

Comment: Где этот код должен выполняться? На сервере?

Comment: В javascript провести проверку и если ошибка есть - отправить name при помощи ajax (без перезагрузки страницы) в php. А там, если name получен - провести удаление из базы.

Comment: Да он должен выполняться на сервере

Comment: Тогда зачем js? Прекрасно справится php

Comment: у меня проверка на CORS, проблемы возникают при JS, а с помощью php я не найду ошибку

Comment: Ошибка то в чем? В коде JS? То есть надо сэмулировать работу JS парсера в ПХП?

Comment: есть потоки m3u8, при использовании hls.js выскакивает ошибка связанная с CORS, вот мне и надо отобрать те ссылки с потоками в которых есть такая ошибка и удалить их.